# Downloading data from Google App Engine Application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html

Here it is explained how to download data from a gAE app,

First thing to do is setting up remote_api.
     The bulk loader tool communicates with your application running on App Engine using remote_api, a request handler included with the App Engine runtime environment that allows remote applications with the proper credentials to access the datastore remotely. There are two ways to install remote_api: automatically using the builtins directive, or you manually using the url directive.

I enabled it using builtins directive:
i changed app.yaml accordingly

```
builtins:
-  remote_api: on
```

Its given that this directive finds "include.yaml" file for the remote_api and maps the request handler to /_ah/remote_api. Only administrators of the application can access this URL.

but i never came across include.yaml

after that i tried downloading data using the the commands given there

```
appcfg.py download_data --application=<app-id> --url=http://<appname>.appspot.com/[remote_api_path] --filename=<data-filename>
```

i'm getting an error saying permission denied, i'm confused. i am also not able to use "create_bulkloader_config" command, getting the same error, I'm confused, Thanks

Comment: are u using your application in a custom domain ?

Comment: You need to include your complete command line, error messages, and stack traces.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using open ID / federated login for your app? The remote API does not work with open ID, but there is a workaround here:

http://blog.notdot.net/2010/06/Using-remote-api-with-OpenID-authentication

Comment: thanks for responding, no i'm using google login..
in the documentation, there is another procedure, like creating exporter classes and so on, i will try  that. but i dont understand why these simple commands arent working for me

Comment: are you saying that we cannot use remote api if i didnot implement users service?

Comment: sorry for late reply, i went to sleep after a long night

Comment: i want to be more clear, i wrote an app, which uses google authentication earlier.. it is using master/slave datastore.

after that i changed app.yaml to enable remote_api, and updated it using my login credentials. after that i tried downloading the data using that simple command and am getting an error saying "IO:Error [error no 13] permission denied:'c://programfiles/gae/bulkloader-log-20110513.175624".

am i missing something? i am a noob so please help me

Comment: successflly did it after fiddling with it for 3 hours :) nick i'm following your blog from now

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
builtins:
-  remote_api: on
```

With

```
- url: /remote_api
      script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
      login: admin
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should run the commandline as an admin user. The permission denied error you are getting refers to the appcfg script not being able to access a local file.